# Best workflow/approach for dev teams on localhost

Tags: localhost

I've been a freelancer working solely on my own with all my EE installs on localhost on my Mac. Soon it looks like I'll need to collaborate in my home office with another EE dev so am looking for suggestions as to the best workflow set-up.

Basically we'd both be working on the same EE dev site in the same office but on our individual laptops. What's the best approach to facilitate this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is networking question more then the EE question. But I can give you some suggestions:

1. You can migrate your site to any temporary or development server and use files from that server via FTP. (To prevent the site to list in google list while development, you can put robots.txt file on public html folder)
2. In your same system, one can connect your localhost if both pc connected via LAN. so if your IP is 1.1.1.1 I can use your localhost as http://1.1.1.1/ee
3. You can put all your code in GIT, so you can create a branch, pull it in morning. work all day and push the changes to git at evening.

There are many more ways to do so depending on you.